# Testing - Hybrid test automation framework in Selenium

Tags: selenium, frameworks, automation, hybrid

I am moving to Selenium after years of working in QTP. I have built and used hybrid automation frameworks in QTP.

Is there a similar framework in Selenium? I am looking for a similar one as it will help ease the transition for me and my team.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the list you can start with :

1. [Robot Framework (lang : Python and Java)](http://robotframework.org/)
2. [Fitnesse (lang : .Net and Java)](http://fitnesse.org/FrontPage)
3. [Cucumber : (lang : Ruby)](http://cukes.info/)
4. [ISFW (InfoStretch Selenium Framework) : (lang : Java)](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/ISFW-latest-build-released-4014456.S.274479844)
5. Many more customized open source frameworks using underlying unit testing frameworks.

All of these are more or less hybrid frameworks and Selenium is browser automation library which is used by all frameworks.

To prepare your own framework, you can start with unit testing framekworks like TestNG, JUnit, NUnit based on your preferred language.

Comment: Is it possible to implement jUnit test for Hybrid using roboelectric?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. Selenium is different from QTP in that Selenium is a library for driving browsers, not a full test tool with things like logging or even the concept of a test case. Often it's paired with a unit testing tool like TestNG or NUnit to get some of that functionality, but it doesn't have any framework built in.

On a wider scale though, frameworks do exist like what I believe you're asking about (where hybrid means a framework that uses both the keyword-driven and data-driven patterns). One recently released is Golem. Prototest created it and open sourced it a couple of months ago. You can find more on it [here](http://prototest.com/golem-a-new-open-source-test-automation-framework/). It's not an official piece of Selenium, but might be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks Andy for the info. Yes, typically selenium tests are different because typically java developers work in selenium who have a different world view from testers IMHO. Golem is good but it is in C#. Guess I will have to build a simple one in Java.